# My drop down menu is not working in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have created a custom menu in the wordpress. That menu has pages with childs.

The drop down menu works in firefox and chrome but did not work in IE.

Here is my CSS code.

```
/* =Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#access {

    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
#access ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9999 !important;

}
#access li {

    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999 !important;

}

.menu .menu-item:hover {
background:#89ab20;
}
#access a {
color:white;
padding-right: 24px;

    text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.8em;
    left: 0;
    width: 188px;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color:#89ab20;

}
#access ul li ul li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: list-item;
    float: none;

}
#access ul li ul li a:hover {
background-color:#0086b2;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.sub-menu {
background-color:#89ab20;
}
.sub-menu .menu-item:hover {
background-color:#0086b2;
}

#access ul ul a {
    font: normal 11px Verdana;
    width: 135px; /*width of sub menus*/
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0;
    border:none;
    background-image:none;
    border-bottom:#fff solid 1px;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    border-bottom:none;
    display:block;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background-color:#0086b2;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
color:#fff;
    background-color:#89ab20;

}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#access ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#access .current-menu-item > a,
#access .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.current_page_item {
    background-color: #89AB20;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And here is my html which is generated. Please any one who can solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="navigation">
                            <nav role="navigation" id="access">
                                <h3 class="assistive-text">Main menu</h3>
                                                            <div class="skip-link"><a title="Skip to primary content" href="#content" class="assistive-text">Skip to primary content</a></div>
                                <div class="skip-link"><a title="Skip to secondary content" href="#secondary" class="assistive-text">Skip to secondary content</a></div>
                                                            <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul class="menu" id="menu-main-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69 first-child" id="menu-item-69"><a href="">About</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-141 first-child" id="menu-item-141"><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-140" id="menu-item-140"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-64" id="menu-item-64"><a href="">About</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-67 first-ch

ild" id="menu-item-67"><a href="">About</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68 first-child" id="menu-item-68"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65" id="menu-item-65"><a href="">About</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-66 first-child" id="menu-item-66"><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-230 last-child" id="menu-item-230"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</li>
</ul></div> 
</nav><!-- #access -->
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work in IE_. What doesn't work?

Comment: I have created a drop down menu in wordpress. On mouse over the page list its child. But in IE the childs did not display when I over the mouse on the page. I am talking about the navigation menu.

Comment: What version of IE? Does it happen in IE9? It would be usful if you put up an example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Then your problem is probably `z-index: 9999 !important`. Try removing those and reorganizing your css properly. Using `!important` means something is wrong. Also `z-index` works only in positioned elements. So in `#access ul` it's probably doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with jquery. As IE does not support LI:Hover property. So I follow this link to add css class to selectors using jquery.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/drop-down-menu-not-working-in-ie#post-1065267